# Детекция светодиодов на изображении

Tags: c++, opencv

Только знакомлюсь с OpenCV, нужно реализовать программу по вычислению координат на изображении светодиодов (рисунки ниже). Как можно сделать это наиболее эффективно? Проблема ещё в том, что на фоне могут присутствовать посторонние объекты, а так же светодиоды на изображении не всегда имеют строго синий цвет (может варьироваться от очень светлых до темных).

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Mat pic; // твоё изображение
Mat mask; // то что получиться
img = imread("Svetodiod.jpg"); 
cvtColor (pic, pic, COLOR_BGR2HSV); //конвертация цветов в HSV не обязательно

Scalar min(minH, minS, minV); // Минимальные данные твоего цвета
Scalar max(maxH, maxS, maxV); // Максимальные данные твоего искомого цвета

inRange(pic, min, max, mask); //собственно сама функция поиска. 
//на картинке pic ищет цвета между  min и max и потом выведет их в mask
```

на Scalar прикручивай ползунки, подбирай цвет.

а дальше на mask ищи обьекты, там по разному. например переведи в контуры с помощью findContours() и найди их центры тяжести или момент.

или boundingRect() вернет тебе квадрат, окружающий эти контуры (с mask)

Comment: в идеале, конечно, нужно автоматизировать процесс подбора минимально, максимального значения цвета. Спасибо за идею

Comment: если цвет меняется кардинально, возможно нужен другой подход. судя по фото метод inRange() должен подойти. всего лишь один раз настроив его. 

Можно попробовать затемнить сцены, сделать контрастной и выделять яркие участки.  отсеять шум по площади контура . или применить наращивание erode()

Нужно больше информации. Камера будет двигаться? на картинке будет меняться только положение светодиодов или другие предметы тоже? ну в идеале пример конечно, как меняются отслеживаемые обьекты

Comment: могли бы мы с вами пообщаться в личных сообщениях, мог бы более детально объяснить проблему и показать примеры

Comment: пишите на почту daiman.abigor@gmail.com